# Changing values in a list using ValueChanged

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of doubles that I want to change its value whenever I click on a Button on another script.

The code script to send the values into the button script is like this

```
List<double> values = [0,0,0,0,0,0]


ListBuilder(
 itemCount: values.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Column(
   Text(values.toString),
   TouchSpin(
     currentValue = values[index];
     onChanged = onChanged;
    ),
   );
  }
)
```

But if I do this, the onChanged would only change one of the values as I declare the onChanged function like this

```
  ValueChanged<double> onChanged = (value) {};
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    onChanged = (value) {
      setState(() {
        values[0] = value;
      });
    };
  }
```

I tried creating a list for onChanged but it doesnt initialize
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: you have to pass the index  of the list

Comment: but the onChanged function doesnst accept an index though....

Comment: try this `ValueChanged<List<double>> onChanged`
you can update whole list insted

Comment: it works normally but in this case the TouchSpin is shared between different scrips and it doesnt fit both...

Comment: what do you mean "different scrips " ?

Comment: i suggest you tu use state management , it will realy simple to achive

Comment: alright... i will check on that... any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to change value and call it in initstate

```dart
 onChanged(index, value) {
  setState ((){
   values[index]= value;
});
};
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    onChanged(0,1);
  }
```

Comment: wait... how does this work? I mean... how do we change different values though?
Forgive me if I dont understand... i am still new to flutter and stuff

Comment: you just change the value for index[0] , the  issue is to update the value on list , not just index 0

Comment: It is just an example to show how to change a value by creating a method. In the question I saw value[0] so suggested how to achieve that.

Comment: Edited my answer, You can pass both index and its value and that specific value is updated and sets state

Comment: @KaushikChandru i think you cannot pass 2 props for `ValueChanged`

Comment: I am not changing value changed.. onChanged it a normal method that updates a List<double>'s value.